# How to get data from MySQL database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database and echo a variable that's created from the data.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
// Connects to Our Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "escalat1_local", "database88") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("escalat1_local") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$variable= print_r($row); // This will show it to you 
echo $variable;
?>
```

This is how it's being displayed:

```
Array ( [0] => white haven center ) 1
```

How do I make it just display this?

```
white haven center
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Dont' use the `mysql_*`functions. They're not maintained anymore and officially deprecated. Use either DBO or mysqli. (see official documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: FYI as of PHP 5.5.0 mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: Just updated question.

Comment: Use echo $row["cities"];

Comment: That removed the `1` at the end but now it still displays like `Array ( [0] => white haven center )`

Comment: @user3344106: **WHY** do you perform `print_r` then? Do you understand what it is for? If not - why haven't you checked the php documentation first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it (you said your column is also called cities) :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT cities FROM cities ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["cities"];
```

FYI as of PHP 5.5.0 mysql_* functions are depreciated.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This line i think must have a bug :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($row);
```

Must be changed to :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, it should be really simple:

```
echo $row[0];
```

Also that `print_r` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

use `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

instead of `$row = mysql_fetch_array($row);`

Answer (score 0):

This is just for one row if you want to do it for all rows then you have to create a for loop

```
Array ( [0] => white haven center ) 1
echo $row[0];
//output-> white haven center
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code,

Simply change

```
echo $variable;
```

to

```
echo $variable[0];
```